# ASP.NET binding partial View droplist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, partial-views

My code is similar to:

class StudentsViewModel:

```
public class StudentsViewModel
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public Student SelectedStudent { get; set; }
    public string DisplayMode { get; set; }
}
```

StudentsController:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(int? page, int? SelectedGroup)
{
    // some code

    StudentsViewModel model = new StudentsViewModel();
    model.Students = db.Students.ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
    model.SelectedStudent = null;
    model.DisplayMode = "WriteOnly";
    ViewBag.IDGroup = new SelectList(db.Groups, "IDGroup", "Name");
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

View: Index

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Add Student" formaction="/Students/new" class="btn btn-default" />


//some code

@{
    if (Model.SelectedStudent != null)
    {
        if (Model.DisplayMode == "ReadWrite")
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("_EditStudent", Model.SelectedStudent);
        }
    }
    if (Model.DisplayMode == "WriteOnly")
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_InsertStudent", new StudentList.Models.Student());
    }
}</form>
```

Partial View:
_InsertStudent.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownList("IDGroup", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDGroup)
</div>
```

I have very big problem because my DropDownList doesn't work... Now I display _InsertStudent when I click on button but it doesn't work... If i have

```
Html.RenderPartial("_InsertStudent", new StudentList.Models.Student());
```

directly (without button) it works...

Comment: It showing any error or drop down list is empty?

Comment: Its a bit unclear what your trying to do. Your generating a dropdownlist outside the form tags so it wont post back anything.

Comment: In case of ((selectstudent == null) && (displaymode == ReadWrite)) you will not get any partial view. This is want you want?

Comment: I want to display _InsertStudent partial view after click on "Add student" button.

Comment: Did you define your model on top of the partial view, because it is missing in the snippet.